# VSTS: Test Case Added from Work section not available in Test section

Tags: testing, azure-devops, testcase, test-suite

I added a Test Case from the Work area.  Its been a week maybe so I don't remember if it was from the Backlog or the Board.

Now when I go to Test / Test Plans it is not showing up.  I cannot find a way to add it to a Test Suite.

I can add Test Cases to Test Suites via the Test area.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the Test Case to your Test Suite/Plan manually.

Navigate to the test plan/test suite, -->  `Add existing` --> Edit the query to filter the Test cases --> `Run query` --> Select the Specific Test case and click `Add Test cases`

Please note that you need to install the [Test Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-testmanager-web) extension from Extension marketplace, and make sure you have a license for Test Manager Extension.

Please go to Users tab: `https://{account}.visualstudio.com/_admin/_users` , check whether you have Test Manager Extension.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I did not have Test Manager but after installing it this worked perfect.